# How do I bring the nut closer to the washer?

Tags: bolts, washer

Following my [last question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/254254/how-to-repair-my-exhaust-fan-bolt/254256#254256) (thanks @crip659 !), I was able to put the nut back on.

However, now it is stuck at this kind of middle level where the threads stop. When I removed the whole thing from the exhaust fan, the nut and the washer were stuck together.

How can I bring them closer again? I tried turning in every direction but it doesn't change. I don't want to go too hard and break the bolt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assuming that the nut ties down the fan.

It does not do that.

The nut goes only to the end of the tread, it does not tie down the fan and is not in contact with the washer

Under the nut it is the black thingy (washer), that slides over the bolt in specific place, not in contact with the nut.

The fan has to be free to rotate on the bolt.

Answer (score 1):

Stop where the threads stop.

That little e-clip is what holds the fan in place.  There should be a circle/groove cut into the shaft for the e-clip.  Might need to lightly tap the fan down to see it.

Comment: Mmh.. I tried to see but I have no idea where it comes from. I tried to remove the fan but it is stuck and I don't want to push too hard.

Comment: If it helps, here is the model: https://apps.mecanair.net/mecanair/st/i2reppiecepub.asp?id1=&ki20586=1&langue=F&ki20503=56&ki20504=458&ki20500=79571&ki20503ori=56

Comment: @NicolasSC  I am guessing here, but think that that nut holds number 9, shaft goes though a hole in #9 and then the nut holds the bracket.  If the fan is really struck on the shaft, the e-clip is almost optional(but I did not say that).

Comment: Yeah maybe, but it fell out after I unscrewed it out of the bracket. I will check, but thanks!